# How to get the output 123456789101112131415 of type integers?

Tags: javascript

Could anyone explain why I get the output: 123456789101112120000

when the expected output is: 123456789101112131415

I am using Visual Studio Code and node.js

```
blah = 15
for (var i = 1 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
    output *=10    
output += i 
}

for (var i = 10 ; i <= blah ; i++) {
    output *=100 
    console.log(i + ' ' + output)  
output += i 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're manipulating numbers, which do not remain precise after a number of significant figures. Either use BigInts instead, which do not have such a limitation:

```js
blah = 15
let output = 0n;
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  output *= 10n
  output += BigInt(i)
}

for (var i = 10; i <= blah; i++) {
  output *= 100n
  output += BigInt(i)
}
console.log(String(output))
```

Or use strings instead:

```js
let str = '';
for (let i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
  str += i;
}
console.log(str);
```